# Cast base class to generic class of T

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

i have a base class called Event which is inherited by Generic class type called RequestModel now i have to convert base class object to derived class without knowing type of "T" in request model. Following is the thing that i have done. Thank you in advance for helping.

```cs
public class RequestModel<T>:Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public T Model{ get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string EntityType => typeof(T).ToString();

    public override Type RequestEntityType { get { return typeof(T); }}
    public UserDataViewModel UserData { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

    public RequestModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public abstract class Event
{
    public abstract Type RequestEntityType { get; }
}
```

i have collection of event class where i add RequestModel

```
public List<Event> AllEvents = new List<Event>();
```

Here is the function where i get each event out of collection

```
public void RunLogEvent()
{
    foreach (var eventItem in AllEvents)
    {
        try
        {
            var mappedData = MapData(eventItem);
            _creditCardLogService.Add(mappedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Here is the MapData function where is type conversion to which i actually need to convert event object to RequestModel object

```
private CreditCardLog MapData(Event request)
{
    var b = Activator.CreateInstance(request.RequestEntityType);
    var a = CastToMyType(b, request);

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var returnData = new CreditCardLog()
    {
        AppraisalFormID = ApparisalId,
        CreatedBy =null ,
        CreatedDate = a.LogDate,
        LogID = a.Id,
        Data = serializer.Serialize(a.Model)
    };
    //return returnData;
    return returnData;
}

public  RequestModel<T> CastToMyType<T>(T NeededType, object givenObject) where T : class
{
    var newObject = givenObject as RequestModel<T>;
    return newObject;
}
```

last function `CastToMyType<T>` is the casting function which i desperiately need to cast object to `RequestModel<T>` type which i am right now unable to do so please if anyone could help it will be great. thank you.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is obsolete and shouldn't be used. ASP.NET Web API itself uses Json.NET. JavaScriptSerializer doesn't even use the defacto date standard, ISO8601

Comment: serialization is not my problem . actually i have problem in casting

Comment: Why not have `Event` have an abstract method `ToCreditCardLog` which will be overriden in derivatives? Then casting is completely superfluent.

Comment: It *is* a serious problem. In all that hard to read code, it's the one thing that's immediatelly obvious. As for the rest, post only the relevant code, highlighting where the problem is. Right now, people have to read everything to understand what you're asking. And JavaScriptSerializer is the most obvious problem

Comment: @damonshahi as for casting, you can't cast a concrete type to a generic type. Casting doesn't *change* the object, it allows you to use it through a different interface.

Comment: @damonshahi the other obvious problem is the `catch (Exception ex){            continue;}`. Why don't you use LINQ's `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>()` ?

Comment: If you don´t know the exact type at compile-time, why not extract a non-generic base-interface, which all your generic classes implement, and cast to that instead? Otherwise you simply cannot cast, because casting is a **compile-time**-thing where you know the actual type only at **runtime**.

Comment: Using an interface will be a *lot* faster and avoid allocations as all the reflection overhead goes away. All this code could be reduced to a single LINQ query, eg `allEvents.OfType<IRequest>().Select(req=>new CreditCardLog{AppraisalFormID = ApparisalId,
        CreatedDate = req.LogDate,
        LogID = req.Id,
        Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req.Model)}).ToList();`

Comment: I suspect there are more problems that have to do with the overall architecture, which could be fixed if the architecture was simplified. For example, an EF DbContext *is* a UnitOfWork already, there's no need for another one. The type of the entities loaded by EF is known, there's no need to pass it around as a field.  Typically, models are mapped from the web API layer, to the business layer to the data layer. They aren't combined in a single class.

Comment: And this RequestModel class looks like a way to transfer a request's context around, even though it seems to mix up different layers. *And* try to act as a DDD Event, even though it's not. Essentially, it contains some metadata plus some baggage in the form of UserData and Model. The important data though is very specific. It would be a *lot* easier to use it if the context data was exposed through either a base class or an interface

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos yup you are right brother it  a way to transfer a request's context around and save that request as a event in db. and can you explain how it would be easy if i expose data in base class. I would be great help from you to me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Event class list in the T Model of RequestModel class as it is generic type.

```
public class RequestModel<T>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    public RequestModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Now define the function where you can log the event.

```
public void LogEvent(RequestModel<List<Event>> request)
{
    foreach (var eventItem in request.Model)
    {
        try
        {
            var logData = new CreditCardLog()
            {
                AppraisalFormID = ApparisalId,
                CreatedBy = "UserID",
                CreatedDate = request.LogDate,
                LogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(eventItem)
            };
            _creditCardLogService.Add(logData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

To convert model to RequestModel you can also create an extension method.

```
public static RequestModel<T> ToRequestModel<T>(this T model)
{
    return new RequestModel<T>()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Model = model
        // assign other property value
    };
}
```

Now, you can convert the list of event to RequestModel by calling ToRequestModel method.

```
List<Event> ev = new List<Event>();
var request = ev.ToRequestModel();
LogEvent(request);
```

Also, if there is different types of Event then you should inherit abstract Event class in those Event classes instead of RequestModel class.

Answer (score -1):

You could invoke your method via reflection.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Example).GetMethod("CastToMyType");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(e.RequestEntityType);
generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { e.RequestEntityType, e });
```

see the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b6juHI)